# Как пропатчить qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick

В Qt начиная с версии 5.6 есть косячек, связанный с QML. При определенных обстоятельствах не отображается MapCircle. [Сам баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54188) В комментариях есть ссылка на фикс

> https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/161978/ should fix this

Каким образом его применить? Хотелось бы узнать универсальный способ, чтобы работало для всех ОС. На сколько по правильно скачать файлы из раздела Patch Set 11 (см ссылку с фиксом) и заменить их у себя?

Comment: Зачем? Чем не устраивает использование более свежей версии Qt?

Comment: @ixSci, баг не исправлен начиная с 5.6. В 5.7.0 он тоже наблюдается. А вот в 5.7.1. вроде бы исправит эту ситуацию

Comment: Тогда из git'а просто возьмите саму свежую версию и соберите её.

Answer (score 1):

абсолютно корректно, пока вы не собрались распространять исходники qt по куче систем. и пока вы используете версию, для которой был произведен этот патч (5.6, допустим)

можете запатчить, это более стабильно, поскольку вы можете внести нужные изменения в 5.7  - т.е. только то, что затронул конкретно этот фикс, а не просто заменить файлы от 5.7 файлами 5.6

вот как работать с командой [patch](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/)

уверен, что под винду она тоже есть или со слоем совместимости (в win10), или mingw/cygwin, под мак тоже есть.

если разница между версиями слишком сильная, накатите этот патч с помощью meld или подобных инструментов

Comment: В своем случае я использую 5.7. Возможно хватит простой замены файлов?

Comment: сравни их, если они не менялись или менялись не сильно, вполне может хватить. иначе рискуешь забыть про них, а потом ловить глюки по несовместимости, пока не вспомнишь